# "there is no package called" error during installation of sjPlot

Tags: r, sjplot

```
library("sjPlot", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.2")
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
there is no package called ‘pbkrtest’
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘sjPlot’
> sjp.lmer(fitted2, type = "fe")
Error: could not find function "sjp.lmer"
```

I have installed the package, so does anyone know why this is giving me this error message above after I enter the following code? Thanks

```
library(lme4)
sjp.lmer(fitted2, type = "fe")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like package [pbkrtest](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pbkrtest/index.html) is missing, which is a dependency of some packages that are used by **sjPlot**.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Do you know how to download this package, as can't find it when I search for it.

Comment: Didn't have latest version of R, so I couldn't download it.  Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to hear it works now. If I answered your question, would you mind accepting my answer?

Comment: Do you know how to edit the x and y axis on all the plots that this code creates at the same time? (It creates 17 different plots)                   sjp.lmer(fitted2, type = "fe.pred")

Comment: Currently, you have to use a workaround with the returned plot-objects (which are in the returned list **plot.list**):
`all.plots <- sjp.lmer(fit, type = "fe.pred")
library(ggplot2)
all.plots$plot.list[[1]] + labs(x = "my x axis title", y = "my y axis title")`

Comment: Thanks again. Works perfectly!