# How to load the package {sjPlot} in R?

Tags: r, package, sjplot

There's an older post from a year ago, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35518656/sjplot-error-message), that touches upon a similar issue. Now I'm facing almost axactly the same issue as Bikash was approximately a year ago. However, the solution suggested there, does not seem to work in my case.

The error message when loading {sjPlot} with library(sjPlot) reads:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘sjPlot’
```

It also tells me (loosely translated from German):

```
Error: Object ‘asis_output’ not exported by 'namespace:knitr'
```

So whatever that means, I thought I try loading {knitr} first and then try loading {sjPlot} again. But I ran into the exact same error message...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess you don't have all dependencies or latest package versions installed.

Comment: Sorry of my late response. You're absolutely right. Problem solved. Thank you, Daniel. ;)